# (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.land) return null

Tags: android, r.java-file

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if(findViewById(R.id.landT)==null)
    {
        mTwoPane=false;
    }
    else{
        mTwoPane=true;
    }
   FrameLayout f =(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.land);
}
```

// XML Of activity_main

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:baselineAligned="false"
android:divider="?android:attr/dividerHorizontal"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context="com.example.progg.movie.ConnFragment"
android:id="@+id/landT">



<fragment
    android:id="@+id/connfragment"
    android:name="com.example.progg.movie.ConnFragment"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.4"
    tools:layout="@android:layout/list_content" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/land"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.6" />
```

this program for Mobile app i have task to convert app to appear in tablet put i face this problem i cant solve it , 
(FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.land) return null  , and f = null

Answer (score 0):

In your xml you have

```
android:id="@+id/land"
```

In your java code you have

```
if(findViewById(R.id.landT)==null)
```

you need to remove the stray T it should be `R.id.land`

Comment: i remove it and the problem appear till nw

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying, the problem only appears when you remove the t?

Comment: after remove t , the problem didnt end till now findViewById(R.id.land) = null